# Start tomcat at windows 7 startup?

Tags: tomcat7

I have tomcat 7 installed on my windows 7 machine. To start it, I have to start it manually all the time. It does not start when I reboot my machine. Any ideas how to enable tomcat to run automatically when windows 7 boots up or is that not possible in tomcat?

Comment: I recommended this resource: http://technology.amis.nl/blog/12278/two-tips-using-xampp-apache-tomcat-on-windows-7-getting-started/comment-page-1#comment-481092 . It allows run Tomcat 7 as Windows service.

Answer (score 14):

(Optional) If you've installed Tomcat as a service, you can configure it to start automatically when the computer boots:

Start > Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services (for open service)

and then : Right Click "Apache Tomcat" > Properties

and then : Set "Startup Type" to Automatic

final : Click Start or restart your pc

***--> https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Step+3+-+Install+Tomcat

Answer (score 2):

Just make a startup shortcut, or, if you don't want to be logged in, run it as a service.

This is for 6.0, but should still apply:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: i read the link you provided and failed on the first hurdle opening cmd.exe in admin mode and typing in service.bat install

It fails saying no such command

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Modifying Tomcat7.exe and Tomcat7w.exe compatibility properties solved the problem. Go to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin\ (or wherever you installed Tomcat) and open Tomcat7.exe properties. Then go to Compatibility tab, Privilege Level and check "Run this program as an administrator". Repeat for Tomcat7w.exe, check that Tomcat7 service is set to run on windows startup and reboot your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Java Service Wrapper, e.g. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp (there's a free community edition, and some googling should turn up similar software).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

Got the Errors when setting up as a service, but solved using the bat file 
Solution:
create a bat file to Start Tomcat7

copy the bat file in windows Startup folder(will be in C:\Users\userName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup)

it will allow the program to launch upon starting up Windows 7

Comment: bat file example: @echo off
pushd  D:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.42-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\
call startup.bat

Comment: For All Users on a Specific Computer:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are several ways, or problems, which prevent tomcat from starting. i have tried a lot, but nothing succeeded. In the end, i went to the "Administrator"- Panel and there for "services". In "**service**", there are all the services, their status, description, the way of starting and the account, which is used to start the service. There, i tried to start tomcat and i told me, that the account was not able to do it (although i configured it in the properties of the tomcat7.exe). So i gave the admin account, password for the service (Logon in the Properties of the service) and then tomcat was able to start and did it again when i rebooted the system.

Answer (score 0):

set the environment variable

JRE_HOME

JAVA_HOME

CATALINA_HOME

CLASSPATH

PATH

THEN

copy msvcr71.dll from JAVA_HOME/BIN TO CATALINA_HOME/BIN

now run  startup.bat